# Why does java decompiler does not save annotations

Tags: java, decompiling, decompiler

Why a decompiled java files does not have any annotations in it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some annotations have their retention set to source code only.

See the [Annotation Retention Policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html):

> Annotation retention policy. The constants of this enumerated type describe the various policies for retaining annotations. They are used in conjunction with the Retention meta-annotation type to specify how long annotations are to be retained ..
>
> .. *SOURCE* Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.